# How to import only required functions/classes from Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars in an Angular application and currently I have imported it as `import * as Handlebars from 'handlebars';` But I want to import only required members of Handlebars such as `import {registerHelper,compile} from 'handlebars';`
It is working good with import * but when I try named imports, it gives me this error when I try testing the file-
[image]

Can anyone help me regarding this? I just want named imports to work. Lots of thanks in advance!
**Handlebars version - 4.7.7

Angular version - 14.2.7**

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on the library what it exports from the module. In `handlebars`, `Handlebars` is the only exported object, so cannot have named imports.

However, you may destructure it this way:

```js
import * as Handlebars from "handlebars";

const {registerHelper, compile} = Handlebars;
```

Otherwise, you may also refer them as `Handlebars.registerHelper()` and `Handlebars.compile()`.